# How to increase UITextField height in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, xib, outlet

I'm creating `UITextField` using `Xib`.  That default height is 30.  But I want to increase that text field height to 40.
Here I had created the outlet and mapped to files owner, then I wrote below line of code.

```
[textfield setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 400, 100)];
```

But The height and width are also not changing as per my coding.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to follow only one step & you will have your solution.

Checkout this image

[image: Select First option from textfield attribute border style]

Enjoy Programming !!

Comment: still Height is not increased.

Comment: after selecting this you need to increase height manually from your xib, this option will allow you to change textfield's height.

Comment: and yes remove this statement [textfield setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 400, 100)]; from your xib

Comment: this is the proper way to do this. Let me know what are you doing?

Comment: I had create text field using xib.set border style None.set one uiimage for that.increased the size to 40 in height property.

Comment: how did you set image for the textfield?

Comment: set ones backgroud color of it bcz then may be your textfild size increes but you can not seen bcz of clear color

Comment: did you remove this statement [textfield setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 400, 100)]; ?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect frameRect = textField.frame;
frameRect.size.height = 100(specify the height you want);
textField.frame = frameRect;
```

Answer (score 0):

set `BorderStyle` to `None` like bellow

```
[textfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
```

and after set frame..

here if your textfield's style is bezier then its frame is fixed and this is the problem so change it with above line

Comment: @user2462484 in `viewDidLoad` method just paste my above line and let me know dear... :)

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];[textfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];[textfield setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 400, 100)];} use this whole code :)